# Problem redirecting console in C#

Tags: c#, console, stdout, stdin

i am building a GUI over an console application that i use, i'm trying to use C# Process and RedirectStandardInput/Error/Output.

The problem is when i redirect anything the console applications stops printing data, i've redirected only stdin and watched the console application window itself, nothing, i've redirected stdin, out and err and no data is received by my program.

This is the only application i tested that doesn't work with Std redirection, is it an implementation issue?

Code:

```
fmproc = new Process();

fmproc.StartInfo.FileName = @"fm.exe";
fmproc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
fmproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
fmproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

fmproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
fmproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
fmproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

fmproc.Start();

fmproc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please also post what console application you are trying to use.

Comment: Posted, it's a default redirection code, and i'm sorry but i can't post the console application. The code reads stdout but i have tested with stderr too.

Comment: You sure the other process is printing a newline character? Else ReadLine() wont do much good :)

Comment: This code i posted uses a ReadLine, i've tried every read method available, it's weird, it's like the process dont use the stdout or stderr but the data is still printed on the screen when using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```
fmproc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
fmproc.WaitForExit();
```

Rather than the ReadLine();  Of course you might want to do something more interesting with the output string - but I'm just following your example code.

Comment: The problem is that the program keep running and doing stuff while up, that why i need to write commands and read responses, i can't wait for exit.

Comment: Fair enough, but what have you tried beyond a single ReadLine() - that's all you're giving us to go on. Does the readline just hang, because there is no newline or what?

Comment: Well i just found 2 problems, one, the first line was empty thats why the ReadLine was empty... and two, the application isn't flushing the buffer after the commands, that was a pretty dumb mistake of mine not checking that right... so, my *new* problem is, can i force the other application to flush?

Comment: Presumably if its working from the command line, it flushes its buffer when it exits.  Why does that not work for your app.   Is this worth the effort I might add? Is the effort of engineering a GUI around it worth what it does - its worth asking yourself whether re-inventing the wheel is worth it in this case.

Comment: I use the program a lot, it would be nice to, at least, automate some unit tests, which are unnecessarily laborious to be done using command line.